# Is it possible to create a symbolic link or shortcut when importing modules?

Tags: python, django

I am using a third party app, `post-office`, in my Django project. I want to make changes to this app rather than including it in `requirements.txt`, so have added the code into my project:

```
-- my-project
    -- my-app
    -- post-office
```

Because I'm doing this for a number of apps, I'd actually like to keep them all in a `vendor` folder:

```
-- my-project
    -- my-app
    -- vendor
       -- post-office
```

When importing modules from this app, I know the correct path is then 
`vendor.post-office.[module]`. However, the `post-office` app itself uses `post-office.[module]` when it imports modules between directories.

Rather than rewriting all the imports from `post-office.` to `vendor.post-office.` is there an easy way to create a symbolic link or shortcut?

Comment: You can clone the repo, make changes, then import the module from your cloned repo

Comment: @GiancarloVentura you mean import via requirements.txt? That would require a private PyPi server...?

Comment: If I import something to my project that is not a pip install, it still has to stay in the project file and therefore under `vendor\post-office`

Comment: you can clone the repo and then import it as an egg in your `requirements.txt` such as:
`-e git://github.com/KhanMaytok/django-mediumeditor.git#egg=django-mediumeditor`. It will work as if you install the original module, but with your changes

Comment: I added an answer and provide an example, please check

Answer (score 2):

A few ways that I can think of offhand:

1. Fork the projects and upload your changes to your own project on PyPI. Depending on the scope of your changes, you can use the forked repo to pull down updates to the upstream repo (if any). Yes, there's overhead to this method, but there are also advantages.
2. If the changes you want to make can be encapsulated, install the dependencies through requirements.txt and then monkey patch your changes from your project. It's a dirty hack but it would prevent having to maintain a fork (either other way) if you're intending to keep the versions in sync.
3. Add the vendored dependencies to `PYTHONPATH`. That way you won't have to include the `vendor` prefix.
4. Add the local dependency paths to `requirements.txt`. `pip` supports installing by file path but last I checked, `setuptools` does not.

Comment: thanks that's really helpful. Could you show an example of how one can extent a `PYTHONPATH` if you are in a docker environment? Does it have to be an absolute system path or can it be relative to the existing `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` works just like `PATH` environment. They all need to be absolute system paths. If you're using docker then you should know where the absolute paths are, in which case you should be able to modify the `PYTHONPATH` through env vars in the container spin-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repo of the python module, made changes and import the forked repo as an egg in your requirements.txt. For example:

You want to made modifications to Faker. The original github repo is: https://github.com/joke2k/faker. In your requirements.txt you have a simple line:

```
Django
Pillow
...
Faker
```

Then you fork the repo and made changes. Your new repo is: https://github.com/YourGithubUsername/faker

Since your new repo is not at PyPI, you should import the repo url in your requirements.txt:

```
Django
Pillow
...    
-e git://github.com/YourGithubUsername/Faker.git#egg=Faker
```

It is ready. You can work with your own version of the library. If you made more changes, you can run `pip install`
 to get the new features of your forked repo